# iOS - Detecting change of contents of CALayer

Tags: ios, calayer, cakeyframeanimation, cadisplaylink

I have a `CALayer` which has a `CAKeyFrameAnimation`.

Is there a way to detect the change of contents of `CALayer`?

It's like, whenever the contents (image) of `CALayer` is changed due to `CAKeyFrameAnimation`, I want to play a short sound with `AVAudioPlayer`.

**UPDATE**

I solved it by doing like this.

```
- (void) viewDidLoad
{
    // init CADisplayLink to catch the changing moment
    CADisplayLink *displayLink = [CADisplayLink displayLinkWithTarget:self selector:@selector(checkContents:)];
    [displayLink setFrameInterval:6] // checking by every 0.1 sec (6 frames)
    [displayLink addToRunLoop:[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];
}

- (void) checkContents:(CADisplayLink *) sender;
{
    // _newImage and _oldImage are class variables. (UIImage)
    // animatingView is a `UIImageView` where its layer's contents is being changed by `CAKeyFrameAnimation`

    CALayer *presentLayer = [animatingView.layer presentationLayer];
    _newImage = presentLayer.contents;
    if ( ![_newimage isEqual:_oldImage] )
    {
        NSLog(@"Image changed! From %@ to %@", _oldImage, _newImage);
    }
    _oldImage = _newImage;
}
```

of course, do not forget to invalidate `CADisplayLink` when it is no more needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you need a `CADisplayLink` to do the job, like described here: [Detecting collision, during a CAKeyFrameAnimation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10431603/detecting-collision-during-a-cakeyframeanimation)

Basically:

> A CADisplayLink object is a timer object that allows your application to synchronize its drawing to the refresh rate of the display.
>
> Your application creates a new display link, providing a target object and a selector to be called when the screen is updated. Next, your application adds the display link to a run loop.

Source: [Apple's documentation on CADisplayLink](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/QuartzCore/Reference/CADisplayLink_ClassRef/Reference/Reference.html)